# iPhone randomly does not make sound when text messages arrive

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, messages, alert

My iPhone 8, model number MX132LL/A, running iOS 16.7.5, sometimes does not beep/ding when a message arrives. I witnessed this myself visually, with the silent switch clearly set to the "Not silent" position. The problem disappeared for a few weeks after a hard reset (restored to factory settings), but then emerged again. Any ideas what could be causing this, or how to fix it?